# What does operator !! do on a string c++

Tags: c++, string, operators

I want to know what would be the return of operator !! on a `_bstr_t` type (string) in c++.

exemple:

```
if (!!mybstr)
{
doSomething()
} else {
doNothing()
}
```

I assume it is a boolean return, but how does it work?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no operator `!!`. It is actually 2 consecutive `!` operators.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`_bstr_t::operator!`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8bsdf5a.aspx) returns `true` if the encapsulated `BSTR` string is `NULL`. So `!!mybstr` will be `true` if the encapsulated `BSTR` string is NOT `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

`!!` is not an operator. It's just two applications of the `!` operator. For plain `bool` values, the net effect is a no-op. For types which have an implicit conversion to `bool`, it's sometimes used to force the conversion to `bool`. For types with `operator!` overloaded, it can do anything, based on the semantics of the `operator!`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x8bsdf5a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Checks if the encapsulated BSTR is a NULL string.

So if you do it twice, then you check if its NOT null first, and then if that is NOT, so you're checking `if (bstr)` essentially.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!!mybstr) = if (!(!mybstr)) = if (mybstr)
```

Comment: While it might seem mathmatically that way, the "operator !" applied twice isn't always the same as "operator bool", some C++ classes only provide one and not the other.